# Why is R^2 negative on random data?

Tags: statistics, regression

The introductory book says R^2 is between 0 and 1, but I have two randomly generated sequences and the R^2 is *negative*. So I read further and now understand the negative value is because R^2 essentially measures how well your model beats a horizontal line. OK, that makes sense.
  So then I made a random sequence that is always either 0 or 1. Obviously the best fitting line is a horizontal line at y=.5 and that prediction will have an error of .5 on every single point. The R^2 of that prediction is 0, so that makes sense.
  But then I made two random sequences that are always either 0 or 1, and the R^2 is still negative. But since each value is either 0 or 1, that means half the points will be identical (error=0) and half the points will be different (error=1), so there should be an average error of .5 exactly like the horizontal line. So why doesn't this random sequence have exactly the same explanatory power as the horizontal line? Why doesn't it also have the same R^2=0 as the horizontal line?

```
np.random.seed(10)
size=100
x = np.arange(size).reshape(-1, 1)
random_1 = np.random.randint(0,2,size=size)
random_2 = np.random.randint(0,2,size=size)

r2_vs_random = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(random_1, random_2)
print(f"R^2 vs random={r2_vs_random}")
plt.scatter(x,random_1);
plt.scatter(x, random_2);
```

Comment: Have you read the scikit learn documentation?  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score

Comment: There is an excellent answer to this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative#12991

Comment: Hi: you should figure out what r2_score is literally doing in terms of a formula. My guess is that it's not doing what you think it's doing. The correlation that 2 random variables have is  pretty different than the R squared that comes out of a regression of one versus the other. The latter needs an intercept to be included or it makes no sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a stats question to which Dave Harris link provides an excellent answer.

Comment: @Bob Jansen: To me.  it's not a relevant answer because the "artificially constrained case" is not applicable to what the person above described. They called a function in python which does "who knows what ?".. But you're right in that it's more of a "what does sklearn.metric.r2_score" do under the hood question which is not terribly relevant for this list.

Comment: @markleeds It might not directly applicable but it does show that $R^2$ can be negative if your model is bad enough. An instance of random predictions can of course be a very bad set of predictions.

Comment: No, the question has nothing to do with sklearn. I've hand-computed it and got the same answer. But ok, if you want to move it to stats instead of quant, then ok.

Comment: @Student: what did you hand compute ?  Bob Jansen: Not trying to be difficult but  I guess I would argue that, if you fit a model with constraints or you use random predictions, then that's not an R^2 coming from a true OLS model fit so it really isn't the true definition of R^2. R^2 is explained ( by the model fit )  variation  over total variation so the concept of a negative rsquared doesn't sit well with me. But maybe that's just me. :).